# Trying to download from URL and save to file with node.js.. what is my issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to download specific files from a URL, but appear am having problems with only a single file being written out. The following is my code:

```
var filenames=["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"];
for(var i in filenames) {
  var url = 'http://myhomepage/'+filenames[i];
  restler.get(url, {
    }).on('complete', function (data) {
      fs.writeFile('./'filenames[i], data, function(err, data) {
      })
    });      
  }
```

It seems that the only file that gets written out is "c.txt" and not the others. What is the issue and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `restler.get` is asynchronous and by the time the first file is being written, the `for` loop is on the last element.  You can get around this by using a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and creating a separate scope for each elem you iterate over:

```
var filenames=["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"];
filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
  var url = 'http://myhomepage/'+filename;
  restler.get(url, {
    }).on('complete', function (data) {
      fs.writeFile('./' + filename, data, function(err, data) {
      })
    });      
  }
} );
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your implementation less changed, you can create a wrapper function to create a separate scope:

```
var filenames=["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"];
for(var i in filenames) {
  (function(i) {
  var url = 'http://myhomepage/'+filenames[i];
  restler.get(url, {
    }).on('complete', function (data) {
      fs.writeFile('./'filenames[i], data, function(err, data) {
      })
    });  
  }(i));    
  }
```

Comment: Is there some event that is triggered upon finishing all the files in the list I could use like an onEnd of some sort where I could console.log done with either of the methods?

Comment: @Rolando: You could use the [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) which lets you specify a `callback` that should be called once asynchronous operations are performed on all elements in a collection.